# A short story where a time traveller gets mistaken for Jesus Christ?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I read this short SF story in around 2008, but cannot remember the title and only vaguely remember the story. I'm not able to find the story on any search site, so I am asking about it here.

I have checked other answers, and the story is not "Let's go to Golgotha!", or "The Didymus Contingency".

A time traveller has to go back to the past for some work. The time machine malfunctions and he ends up in Israel in the time just after crucifixion. As soon as people see him coming out of a tomb, they run after him. He is surprised as to how people recognize him. He finds his way back to the time machine and returns to his time.

He tries another attempt to go back to the past. This time he ends up a little earlier. He gets stuck in the time there, and lives his life teaching people, until he is crucified.

Comment: Nor "Behold the Man" (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behold_the_Man_(novel))?

Comment: Nor "Behold the Man", because the person travelled through time more than once to go to the "correct" time.

Comment: Sounds similar too, but almost certainly isn't, [The Skull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Skull_(short_story)) by Philip K. Dick.  Similar premise, but a completely invented prophet, and several other different details.

Comment: I read the summary of The Skull, and it seems to have the similar story. Will search and read up the whole story once. Thanks, @ArcanistLupus!

Comment: @Paramdeep it's one of Dick's less weird stories, and I found it short, but quite enjoyable.

Comment: Surely (given the story you've outlined, which seems to be a stable time loop) he's not *mistaken* for Jesus, he *is* Jesus?

Comment: @DavidS - Indeed! It is a stable time loop, and he *is* the prophet!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is [The Skull](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/30255) by Philip K. Dick.

I read the short story again, and recalled a few passages, to be sure that it is definitely this one.

---

Apologies that the title and the question is misleading.
I had remembered very little of the original story and apparently added some of my own imagination.
Thanks to @ArcanistLupus for identifying the story even though all that vagueness!